# Как я могу реализовать загрузку данных из торрент-файла используя python?

Tags: python, torrent

Как я вообще могу реализовать загрузку данных из торрент-файла используя python?. Пробовал pyBitTorrent, блокирует пиры после загрузки 1го файла, libtorrent вообще не запускается на 3.10

Answer (score 0):

Для реализации загрузки данных из торрент-файла вы можете использовать библиотеку libtorren.

Вот пример кода:

```
import libtorrent as lt

# Создаем сессию
ses = lt.session()

# Открываем торрент-файл
info = lt.torrent_info('path/to/torrent/file.torrent')

# Добавляем торрент в сессию
h = ses.add_torrent({'ti': info, 'save_path': 'path/to/save/files'})

# Запускаем загрузку
ses.start_dht()

print('Загрузка началась...')

while not h.is_seed():
    s = h.status()

    print('Загружено: {} bytes из {}'.format(s.total_wanted, s.total))

    # Приостанавливаем выполнение на некоторое время
    lt.sleep(1)

print('Загрузка завершена!')
```